# Input dinamicos con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito crear inputs dinamicos

```js
/*Crear input dinamico: distancia de izquierda a derecha entre sanitarios.*/
$('#dynamicSanitary').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var disSanitary = disSanitary;
  var innerhtml = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    innerhtml += "<input type='text' class='form-control big2' placeholder='Distancia' id='" + (i + 1) + "' name='" + (i + 1) + "' size=5>";
  }

$("#dis").html(innerhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 form-control big" id="dynamicSanitary">
          <option selected>Ingrese cant sanitarios</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>

        <div class="col-3  center-block rabbit" id="dis">
        
        </div>

        <select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 form-control big" id="dynamicSanitary">
          <option selected>Ingrese cant sanitarios</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>

        <div class="col-3  center-block rabbit" id="dis">
```

¿Como hacer para que el segundo select también me genere inputs dinamicamente sin tener que cambiar el id?.
lo que se me ocurre es que el id sea dinámico.

Comment: A que te refieres sin tener que cambiar el `ID`?  El `id` es un atributo que no se puede repetir en tu pagina.

Comment: Pues referencíalos por una clase en común y no por un id.

Comment: Me explico, para que genere los inputs el va y mira el id del div el cual es dis, el error esta en que si le doy en el segundo select para que me genere inputs no me da por el id

Comment: en una misma pagina no se puede tener dos elementos del DOM con el mismo id `id="dynamicSanitary"` no se pueden llamar los dos select con el mismo id.
Prueba cambiando `$('#dynamicSanitary')` por `$('.custom-select')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás repitiendo los identificadores de tus elementos en el DOM, y jQuery no tiene cómo adivinar específicamente a qué #dinamicSanitary o #dis te refieres.

Para tu caso de uso, podrías por ejemplo usar clases para referirte a los selectores y sus respectivos divs:

```js
/*Crear input dinamico: distancia de izquierda a derecha entre sanitarios.*/

$('.dynamicSanitary').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var disSanitary = disSanitary;
  var innerhtml = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
  innerhtml += "<input type='text' class='form-control big2' placeholder='Distancia' id='" + (i + 1) + "' name='" + (i + 1) + "' size=5>";
  }
  var dis = $(this).next('.dis');
  dis.html(innerhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 form-control big dynamicSanitary"  >
          <option selected>Ingrese cant sanitarios</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>

        <div class="col-3  center-block rabbit dis">
        
        </div>

<select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 form-control big dynamicSanitary">
          <option selected>Ingrese cant sanitarios</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>

        <div class="col-3  center-block rabbit dis" >
```

Comment: Cuando la pongo en la etiqueta `fieldset` `legend` y  `div` deja de funcionar.

Comment: Al parecer otro usuario editó mi respuesta pero deshice la edición. Por el momento no te compliques la vida. Has simplemente el cambio de ids a clases como aparece ahora

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero cambia el evento de ID a clase

Segundo selecciona el "body" o algun DIV padre de la clase dynamicSanitary y el binding se hará sobre la nueva clase .dynamicSanitary

PD. me tome la libertad de usar ON en lugar de 'change' por que suelo usarlo más.
Eso debería funcionar... problemente.

```
$('body').on('change', '.dynamicSanitary', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var disSanitary = disSanitary;
  var innerhtml = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    innerhtml += "<input type='text' class='form-control big2' placeholder='Distancia' id='" + (i + 1) + "' name='" + (i + 1) + "' size=5>";
  }

$("#dis").html(innerhtml);
});
```