# input dinámico con llenado automático

Tags: javascript, php, script, input

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar
es esta parte creo creo un boto para crearlos input de manera dinámica
si me deja agregar mas input pero  no los llena de manera automática.

pero si creo los impute estáticos si me deja llevarlos de manera dinámica

```
      <div id="divAgregarInputs" class="col-lg-11">
</div>
<script>
var btnElem = document.getElementById('btnAgregar');
var index = 0;
btnElem.onclick = function(evt) {
index++;
var divAgreg = document.getElementById('divAgregarInputs');
divAgreg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
'<input id="autouser2" style="width: 10%;" name="pos'+ index + '" type="text"   ' + '" />'
+ '<input  style="width: 15%;" id=autouser name="nomA'+ index + '" type="text"   ' +'" />'
); }
</script>
```

En esta parte traigo los datos del mi base para rellenar los input de manera automática

```
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#autouser" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
       $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url()?>Main/userList",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
         search: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
         response( data );
        }
       });
      },
      select: function (event, ui) {
       // Set selection
       return false;
      },
      focus: function(event, ui){
         $( "#autouser" ).val( ui.item.label );
         $( "#autouser2" ).val( ui.item.label2 );
       },
     });


  });

  </script>
```

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445487/c%C3%B3mo-llenar-varios-select-agregados-con-javascript-con-la-misma-informaci%C3%B3n)

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56877/input-dinamicos-con-jquery)

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285099/llenar-un-input-de-forma-autom%C3%A1tica-con-otro-input)